# How to reuse css with relative links from sub directories?

Tags: html, css, relative-path

I have some sub pages that I want to reuse the css on, but I have background urls defined relatively which break when accessed from the sub page.

I am willing to use absolute paths, but I need them to be configurable and I'm not sure how I could include config paths in the css.

I've also thought about just using html base tag and sticking with relative

What's the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: Can you provide an example? Typically if a CSS file has a relative path in it, that path is relative to the CSS file so if a page in a different directory points the same CSS file, the paths should still resolve.

Comment: After looking back at this, it seems like I have an issue with my header template and not the css image paths, thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your stylesheet may be set up incorrectly. Typically you should put your css and your images in the same parent directory. Like so:

```
assets > styles > styles.css
assets > images > image.jpg
```

That way your images will always be a relative path inside of the document matching this:

```
background: url(../images/image.jpg);
```

You can then set an absolute path in your HTML link tag and link the current page to the stylesheet like so:

```
<link href="http://mysite.com/assets/styles/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 0):

With how you're currently set up, using the HTML base tag would be your best bet.  It's the cleanest and easiest way to change what you have without moving a ton of stuff around.